# Element 'ToolkitScriptManager' is not a known element

Tags: asp.net

So I have a file called WebParts.aspx which looks like this -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebParts.aspx.cs" Inherits="e.WebParts" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <div>
      <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">


      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page One</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page Two</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page Three</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      </asp:TabContainer>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And that produces the desired results of creating 3 tab panels inside a tab container.

However, when I change that page to use a MasterPage.master to look like this -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebParts.aspx.cs" Inherits="eservice.WebParts"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2"  
  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
  runat="server">

  <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
       <p id="backtoblog"></p>
       <p> Preferences</p>
        <div>


    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <div>
      <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">


      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page One</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page Two</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>Page Three</ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>

      </asp:TabContainer>
  </div>
   </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
      You are not logged in.
      <br />
      Please login to access eservice
    </AnonymousTemplate>
  </asp:LoginView>

  </asp:Content>
```

VS2008 gives me the following warning:

> Element 'ToolkitScriptManager' is not
>   a known element. This can occur if
>   there is a compilation error in the
>   Web site, or the web.config file is
>   missing.

on the following line:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your second file does not contain the line

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

which you have in your first file. Just because the master page knows about the `asp:` prefix and the assembly/namespace you've associated to it, doesn't mean that the child page does.

A better approach would be to register the assembly/namespace/tag prefix inside your web.config, like so:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <system.web>
        <!-- ... -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp"
                     namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
                     assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Element 'ToolkitScriptManager' is not a known element. This can occur
>   if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config
>   file is missing.

Just in case someone runs across this.  The fix for me, was that the **imported project** properties pointed to 4.5.2 framework.  I selected an older framework, and then selected 4.5.2 again.  This got rid of the mentioned error along with dozens of others.

Comment: It would have been nice if you added how or where in Visual Studio you updated the properties.  
Examples: 
- Updating the 'targetFramework=4.5.2' from the Web.config to an older version and back to 4.5.2 doesn't do anything.
- Right-clicking the project and choosing 'Property pages', navigating to the 'Build' tab and updating the Target Framework here also doesn't seem to fix this (for me).

Comment: @Dieter (not sure how to tag you) - I selected the project in Solution Explorer -> Right clicked the project -> Properties (from context menu) -> Application (from left menu) -> Changed "Target Framework" to some other framework and then saved -> Changed "Target Framework" back to the original and then saved.